# What is the Swift equivalent of a Typescript union type?

Tags: swift, typescript

I want to create something like this on Swift It's for Alamofire json parse

```js
interface Question {
  value: string;
  data: [string]
}

interface Advice {
  type: string;
  data: { value: string }
}

interface CurrentItem {
  type: string;
  data: Advice | Question | string
}
```

Comment: What does it mean? `value` can be of `Type1`? `Type2` or `Type3` kind?

Comment: Value can be of Type1 or Type2 or Type3

Comment: This is an anonymous union type in Typescript. Swift only has named union types, in the form of a protocol with multiple conforming types. It's only useful to use these when the 3 types share common behavior that can be expressed as a requirement of the protocol. Typescript can get kind of fast and loose with its types, so beware that just because using a union made sense in TS doesn't mean you should use something similar in Swift.

Comment: I have endpoint which return json with one of three types

Comment: I suggest you create 3 different types instead (3 versions of CurrentItem) and use each for the corresponding endpoint

Comment: I have only one point which return for example Advice or Question or string

Comment: @IgorDoroshenko They you have designed it poorly. Typescript is very loose on its types because it's based on Javascript. On the other hand Swift is very strict about types. Being strict is usually better because it promotes better design patterns. Returning 3 different object types from a function is usually a very bad idea.
Maybe an enum with an associted value would be the correct one here.

Comment: Hahah. For example + operator in python, js add string and can add numbers in some languages can add arrays, etc. Was it design poorly? It's polymorphism dude

Comment: @Alexander TS Union types are sum types as you have to use pattern matching to distinguish the type. Swift enums being a sum type are the closest equivalent to TS unions. Protocols, and their conforming implementations are polymorphic types they are not union types

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use an enum with associated values to represent the different possibilities:

```
enum Data {
  case advice (Advice)
  case question (Question)
  case string (String)
}
```

You can then create your CurrentItem as a Struct

```
struct CurrentItem {
  type: String
  data: Data
}
```

If you're decoding from JSON you'll need to conform the struct to Decodable and write a custom `init(from decoder: Decoder)` method that looks at the data provided and then create the appropriate instance of the Data enum.

Comment: I found some awesome app for creating interfaces for swift on ts
https://app.quicktype.io/

Answer (score 2):

I think in Swift the way you'd handle a union type like this is with protocols.

```
struct Test {
    var value: MyProtocol
}
```

(Note I put `struct` but it can be whatever type of object you need.)

Where `Type1`, `Type2` and `Type3` conform to some shared protocol. Either by construction, or they can be extended to adopt the protocol. This is advantageous because your object doesn't have to be limited to one of three types and handle each one separately, but rather it doesn't have to know about the inner workings of each of the types it has to support.

And where `MyProtocol` would look something like:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var myValue: Bar { get set }
    func myMethod(_ foo: Foo) -> SomeType
}
```

And say you wanted to extend `Type1` to adopt `MyProtocol`:

```
extension Type1: MyProtocol {
    var myValue: Bar { foo }
    func myMethod(_ foo: Foo) -> SomeType { bar }
}
```

Alternatively, Swift has lots of built-in protocols which might already be shared in common between your three types.

Note you could declare a type that conforms to a union of multiple types with `&` but Swift doesn't have a corresponding idea for "this type OR that type".

Note also that if your protocol has `Self` or associated type requirements it cannot be used as a generic constraint as shown above.

Read more about protocols in the [Swift Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html).

However, if your three types don't have anything in common, Swift also has the `Any` type and in your code you can test for each type as needed using conditional casting:

```
struct Test { 
    var value: Any
    func doSomething() {
        if let value = value as? Type1 {
            doTheThing()
        } // etc.
    }
}
```