# Add a dynamic variable to struct

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I have a 2 structs like so:

```
struct StructA: Codable {
    let title: String?
    let subtitle: String?
    let myImage: URL?
}

struct StructB: Codable {
    let title: String?
    let subtitle: String?
    let myImage: UIImage?
}
```

Now, in `StructA`, the variable **myImage** is of type URL? and in `StructB` the variable **myImage** is of type UIImage?. I want the variable myImage to be able to have either URL? or UIImage? as the type so that I can have a single struct instead of two. Can someone help?

I tried to use Generics on the struct so that I can assign structs of different type to the same variable..but couldn't achieve that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65779401/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-a-typescript-union-type !?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53004623/1187415

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single instance to be able to contain either a URL or a UIImage, you need to use an `enum`

```
struct StructAorB: Codable {
    enum ImageKind: Codable 
    {
        case url(URL)
        case image(UIImage) // NB UIImage is not Codable, but this is irrelevant to the question
                            // You'll just need to extend it to conform
        case none
    }
    let title: String?
    let subtitle: String?
    let myImage: ImageKind
}
```

If you find it inconvenient to have switches everywhere, create convenience properties

```
extension StructAorB
{
    var imageAsUrl: URL?
    {
        switch myImage
        {
            case .url(let ret):
                return ret
            default: 
                return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried this, I get the errors: `Type 'StructAorB' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'` & `Type 'StructAorB' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'`

Comment: @bws Sorry, I forgot: ImageKind has to be `Codable`. I've updated the answer

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the `Codable` bit is pretty much irrelevant to the question and, indeed, `StructB` in the question assumes `UIImage` is `Codable` too.

Comment: @JeremyP Now it's giving the errors `Type 'StructAorB.ImageKind' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'` & `Type 'StructAorB.ImageKind' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'`

Comment: @bws OK, you are going to have to write methods manually to encode or decode the type. You were going to have to do that anyway to make UIImage Codable.